# Change accessibility reading order of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uiaccessibility

I am working on a application in which I am implementing accessibility features. My `UINavigationBar` has left and right bar buttons as well as a navigation item title. Current accessibility order is:

> 1. Left bar button
> 2. Right bar button
> 3. Navigation item title

I'd like to change this order to:

> 1. Left bar button
> 2. Navigation item title
> 3. Right bar button

**How do I change the accessibility reading sequence of my `UINavigationBar`?**

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132805/accessibility-for-ios-voiceover-read-order-issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to provide better readability (by fixing grammar mistakes) while also clarifying your question so it can be answered. See [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more editing tips. I also removed the prefix from your question title and used the proper capitalization of UINavigationBar. Good luck!